# Flutter: How to get precise speed and traveled distance as the user moves?

Tags: flutter, geolocation

I'm trying to build a sort of fitness app. I want to know the user speed and also I want to display the distance traveled by the user. I already know how to get it using the Geolocator package but the data isn't enough precise, in fact, I receive location updates even when the user doesn't move (and the traveled distance is incremented). I want to know if there are better solutions. How other fitness apps can be so precise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huawei [Location Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-locationkit/?ha_source=hms1) may help with your issue.

Location Kit combines the Global Navigation Satellite System (GNSS), Wi-Fi, and base station location functionalities into your app to build up global positioning capabilities, allowing you to provide flexible location-based services for global users. Currently, it provides three main capabilities: fused location, activity identification, and geofence. You can call one or more of these capabilities as needed.

For Detail,pls kindly refer [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/introduction-0000001050706106?ha_source=hms1).

Huawei also has provided some HMS Core kit plugins for Flutter:

[Reference documents](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/overview/HMS-Core-Plugin?ha_source=hms1)

[Location Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050191280?ha_source=hms1)

Comment: thank you so much. I wasn't aware of that package and it perfectly suits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm building something simalar with Geolocator for Flutter.
I don't know if you are using `Geolocator.getPositionStream`, I do, where you can set a filter to eliminate noise in movement.
(https://pub.dev/documentation/geolocator/latest/geolocator/Geolocator/getPositionStream.html)

I calculate distance via speed, meters per second, and get that value every second via `intervalDuration` set to 1 second.
Works great in iOS, but just found out yesterday it doesn't at all on Android.  So i was looking for a solution here.

What is your take on the subject?

```
double trip = 0.0;
positionStream = Geolocator.getPositionStream(
    intervalDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high
    )
    .listen((pos) {
    if (pos != null) {
       
        // calculate distance from speed
        trip += pos.speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks like a question rather than answer.

Comment: more like a healthy discussion and sharing ideas